# Error in XLConnect

Tags: r, xlconnect

I am trying to import an excel sheet into r. I used the following code:

```
x <- loadWorkbook("x.xlsx")
b <- readWorksheet(x, sheet="b")
```

The first line works fine, however, running the second gives the following error:

```
Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
  unable to find an inherited method for function ‘readWorksheet’ for signature ‘"jobjRef", "character"’
```

I have no missing values in that sheet.

For the purpose of reproducing, download `trial.xlsx` from https://github.com/ahmedfsalhin/1stpaper.

system info: Yosemite operating system.

Comment: It would be very helpful to post a link to an example workbook that causes this.  That said, Yosemite is brand-new; you may need to reinstall Java and/or wait for new CRAN builds of `Rjava` .

Comment: @CarlWitthoft  I have just updated the question with a link to excel file to reproduce.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft I did update to Java Development Kit 8 (JDK 8) and after installing the XLConnect again, it works fine now.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft Sorry it is not the Java. It is xlsx package that make the confusion.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It appears the "root cause" is that you should add code to specify both the function and the package it belongs to. Type `XLConnect::loadWorkbook` to select the one you want in this case. There's no 'confusion,' or random selection of duplicated function names in  `R`. The choice depends on the load order of all loaded packages.  Use `search()` to see  the order in which packages are checked for the command you've entered.

E.g., at present I get

```
search()
 [1] ".GlobalEnv"            "package:caTools"      
 [3] "package:XLConnect"     "package:XLConnectJars"
 [5] "package:stats"         "package:graphics"     
 [7] "package:datasets"      "package:vecsets"      
 [9] "package:cgwtools"      "package:grDevices"    
[11] "package:utils"         "package:methods"      
[13] "Autoloads"             "package:base"
```

You'll notice that anything in your environment (`.GlobalEnv`) is selected first, and that all loaded libraries override the `base` package, for example.

Answer (score 7):

After lot of struggle found the solution to this. In R studio go to the packages and remove all the packages related to XLConnect and xlsx. Then instal only XLConnect packages by typing

> install.packages("XLConnect", dependencies=TRUE)

After this the issue should not exist.

Comment: It works for me in the situation when i tried to write numeric to cell using writeWorksheet and received the same error.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem while testing out three different packages for loading .xlsx files into R (**XLConnect**, **xlsx**, **gdata**). The solution was to specify the namespace for `loadWorkbook`:

```
d3_wb = XLConnect::loadWorkbook("Megadataset_v3.xlsx")
d3 = readWorksheet(d3_wb, 1)
```

Then it works, no matter if **xlsx** is loaded/installed or not. The error is because there is also a function with the same name in **xlsx** and it is defaulting to using the wrong one, which depends on the order the packages were loaded.

Answer (score -1):

Try this instead 
x <- readWorksheetFromFile("x.xlsx") in XLConnenct package.