# Error on XLConnect::readWorksheet function

Tags: r, xlconnect

I have a line of R code that is giving me an error. The line of code is:

```
var <- readWorksheet(paste(dir.censo, arq.variaveis, sep="/"), sheet = sheet.variaveis)
```

where `dir.censo` holds the directory path of the excel workbook and `arq.variaveis` is the name of the variable holding the file name. Naturally `sheet.variaveis` holds the name of the worksheet that I need. The file is saved as XLSX. Here is the error:

```
Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
  unable to find an inherited method for function ‘readWorksheet’ for signature ‘"character", "character"’
```

I searched that error online, but nothing showed up. If you could help me resolve this problem, I'd greatly appreciate it. Some system information in case you need them:

Operating system: Windows 10

R version: 3.2.3

RStudio version: 0.99.473

Java version: 8.0_66

Again, thanks a lot.

Comment: I forgot to mention one thing. I also tried the same line of code, using XLConnect::readWorksheet instead of just readWorksheet, but it did not help.

Comment: The docs and example at `?readWorksheet` should be your first port of call.

Comment: Yes jbaums, you are right, and that is exactly what I did. But unfortunately it did not help me figure out what was going wrong.

Comment: This question is solved in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26587659/error-in-xlconnect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just figured out how to resolve this issue. I'm just posting the answer here in case someone else runs into this problem, so their search wouldn't be fruitless. I replaced that line of code above with the following two lines:

```
wb <- loadWorkbook(file.path(dir.censo, arq.variaveis))
variaveis <- readWorksheet(wb, sheet = sheet.variaveis)
```

Comment: You can accept your own answer if it solved your problem.