# XLConnect: unable to find an inherited method for function readWorksheet?

Tags: r

I have the following code

```
FXwb <- loadWorkbook("FX_r_2.xlsx")
x <- readWorksheet(FXwb, sheet=1)
```

And I get the error saying unable to find an inherited method for function readWorksheet. This code used to work before, and the only thing I've changed is adding

```
options(java.parameters = "- Xmx1024m")
```

To allow for more memory. Also, my data in Excel got significantly larger (from 200 rows to 7,000) so I'm not sure if that had something to do with it as well.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to reproduce your problem, but I saw no problem:

```
library(XLConnect)
options(java.parameters = "- Xmx1024m")
FXwb <- loadWorkbook("FX_r_2.xlsx")
x <- readWorksheet(FXwb, sheet=1)
str(x)
'data.frame':   7000 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ a: num  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
 $ b: num  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
 $ c: num  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
```

Perhaps you can find the answer in this thread: [Error in XLConnect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26587659/error-in-xlconnect)